# how to iframe web whatsapp on webpage

Tags: html, iframe, whatsapp

is possible if I would like to i frame whatsapp web on my own website, but the barcode does not showing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITCDI.png)

my code :

```
<iframe src="https://web.whatsapp.com/" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="800px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```